# Previously working variables no longer working in C

Tags: c, random, undefined

I was making some changes to my code so it'll randomly give either addition, subtraction, multiplication, division(before it would cycle through each one). But for some reason, previously working variables (question, wrongAnswers, totalQuestions, correctAnswers) are now coming up as undefined. What's causing this and how can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int addition(void){

    int number1, number2, addAnswer, response;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    number1 = rand() % 12;
    number2 = rand() % 12;
    
    addAnswer = (number1 + number2);
    printf("%d + %d = ?\n", number1, number2);
    scanf("%d", &response);
    
        if (response == addAnswer){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
}

int subtraction(void){

    int number1, number2, subAnswer, response;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    number1 = rand() % 12;
    number2 = rand() % 12;
    
    subAnswer = (number1 - number2);
    printf("%d - %d = ?\n", number1, number2);
    scanf("%d", &response);
    
        if (response == subAnswer){
            return 1;
            
        }
        
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    

}

int multiplication(void){

    int number1, number2, multAnswer, response;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    number1 = rand() % 12;
    number2 = rand() % 12;
    
    multAnswer = (number1 * number2);
    printf("%d * %d = ?\n", number1, number2);
    scanf("%d", &response);
    
        if (response == multAnswer){
            return 1;
            
        }
        
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    

}

int division(void){

    int number1, number2, divAnswer, response;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    number1 = rand() % 12 + 1;
    number2 = rand() % 12 + 1;
    
    divAnswer = (number1 / number2);
    printf("%d / %d = ?\n", number1, number2);
    scanf("%d", &response);
    
        if (response == divAnswer){
            return 1;
            
        }
        
        else{
            return 0;
        }
}

int main(void) {
    int response, int question = 0, correctAnswers = 0, totalQuestions = 0, wrongAnswers = 0;
    response = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (response != -1111) {
        
        if (question == 0){
            
            response = addition();
            
        } else if (question == 1){
        
            response = subtraction();
        
        }else if (question == 2){
    
            response = multiplication();
    
        }else {
            
            response = division();
            
        }
        
        if (response == 0){
            wrongAnswers++;
            totalQuestions++;

        }
        
        if (response == 1){
            correctAnswers++;
            totalQuestions++;
        }
    }
    wrongAnswers = (totalQuestions - correctAnswers);
    printf("Out of %d questions, you got %d right and %d wrong.\n", totalQuestions, correctAnswers, wrongAnswers);
    
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Read [example] and then make a [example]. Also, please provide input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Aside: Many years ago a _former_ co-worker was fired for polluting the company's code base with excessive copy/paste coding... Jus' sayin'... No-one wants to scroll through so much redundant source code.

Comment: _Side note:_ You're doing: `srand(time(NULL));` in every subfunction. Remove these and do it _once_ at the top of `main`

Comment: You may want to consider using `rand() % 12 + 1` in those expressions to get a value `1..12`. Otherwise, division by zero will eventually pop up. There's also a lot of scope for refactoring to remove all that duplicate code, since the only real difference is the question you ask and what you do with the input numbers (add/sub/etc).

Comment: I apologize, you deleted your last question after it was closed before I got a chance to drop you a link. I wanted to leave you with an example that was close to what you attempted reading a character at a time. [Rev words in file in-order](https://paste.opensuse.org/d92d1e1fe1cf). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In testing out your code, I immediately received a compiler error due to the extraneous "int" declaration in your list of integers.

```
int response, int question = 0, correctAnswers = 0, totalQuestions = 0, wrongAnswers = 0;
```

The second "int" needed to be omitted.

```
int response, question = 0, correctAnswers = 0, totalQuestions = 0, wrongAnswers = 0;
```

Then, I was able to compile the program.

Next, in testing out the program, I noticed two issues.  First, there was a test for a response of "-1111" for the program to supposedly end; however, the various test functions would only be returning a value of "0" or "1", meaning the program would not end normally even when an answer of "-1111" was entered.  So, to get around that issue, a small test block was added into each function to return the value of "-1111" instead of "0" or "1" so that a normal program wrap up would occur.

```
scanf("%d", &response);

if (response == -1111)
    return response;
```

The other issue was that the "question" variable was initialized to a value of "0", so only addition tests would take place.  So, to allow for other operation tests to occur, a random value from "0" to "3" was derived during each iteration.

```
int main(void)
{
    int response, question = 0, correctAnswers = 0, totalQuestions = 0, wrongAnswers = 0;
    response = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (response != -1111)
    {
        question = rand() % 3;  /* Otherwise, only addition questions appear */
```

With those bits of refactoring, a test run of the program was done.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/RandomOperations/bin/Release$ ./RandomOperations 
7 - 8 = ?
-1
6 + 1 = ?
7
10 + 9 = ?
19
6 * 9 = ?
54
1 * 10 = ?
22
6 * 0 = ?
0
11 - 6 = ?
5
2 + 0 = ?
-1111
Out of 7 questions, you got 6 right and 1 wrong.
```

The biggest takeaway here would be to review your compiler warnings and/or errors to pinpoint problems in your code.  And also it might be wise to refer to tutorial literature in the use of function return information and loop conditions.

Comment: A couple of other things to note - in the division function, there's the possibility that a "divide by zero" could occur and that should probably be guarded against.  And, just viewing the look and feel of the code, there is a lot of statements that are replicated in each function.  Possibly, the tests could be combined into one function using a switch block to discern which type of question to ask.